# Find a pattern of 3 lines of text with grep, then convert into XML

Tags: regex, grep, bbedit

**I'm building a [BBEdit Textfactory](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/benefitsexercise.html) (grep/regex)** that converts a repetitive set of 3 lines into blocks of XML, but I've hit a snag due to my limited understanding of regex.

Each entry has 3 lines -- a name **\1**, a date **\4**, and a paragraph **\6** -- and then the pattern repeats itself.

The only wild card is when the person served in the military: then he/she has a tag after their name: `<FLAG>` **\2**

**Right now I can only get it to partially work.** The flag-tag seems to always append itself to the end of the person's name at position **\1**, even though it has it's own group parenthesis.

The flag needs to be isolated so that it can be placed later in the XML.

Any help would be appreciated! (And regex structuring advice too, if it's really terrible.)

**Here's the original incorrect pattern, for reference:**

```
^([A-z].*)(<[A-Z]{4}>)?(\r?)([A-z].*)(\r?)([A-z].*)(\r?){1}
```

---

**Here's the replace pattern:**

```
<item>\r
<category>Obituary</category>\r
<title>\1</title>\r
<description>\r
<em>\4</em><br />\r
\6\r
</description>\r
<pubDate><DATE></pubDate>\r
\2
</item>\r
```

---

**Here's a sample of the block of text for processing:**

```
<pre>

Wom The. Bat
May 2, 2015
Wom The Bat, 91, of city, formerly of Texas, died in the hospital. He was born in city, California. He is survived by two sons. Condolences: somewebsite.com.
Baz Foo Bar<FLAG>
April 30, 2015
Baz Foo Bar, 88, of city, an Internal Revenue Service tax examiner, died at home. She was born in another city. She is survived by three daughters; 5 grandchildren; and 2 great-grandchildren. Services: 10:30 a.m. Private burial.
John Doe<FLAG>
April 17, 2015
John F. Doe, 51, of city, a structural engineer, died in the city. He was born in the Philippines. He is survived by his wife, son, daughter, and two parents. Visitation: 9:30 a.m. Monday. Eulogy: 10:30 a.m. Mass: 11:15 a.m. Burial: 1 p.m.
Jane Smith
May 1, 2015
Jane "Mary" Smith, 64, of city, a storage specialist, died in the hospital. She was born in city, Rhode Island. She is survived by a son; two brothers; four sisters; and her caregiver. Graveside services: 11 a.m. Monday at cemetary. Urn burial to follow. Condolences: somewebsite.com.

</pre>
```

Comment: Yeah, `[A-z].*` matches a single character in the range `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` as well as `[`,\.`]`, `^`, `_`, and `\`` you then match `.*` which matches everything. That pattern isn't at all what you want there.

Comment: Any suggestion on what it should be to break apart (Baz Foo Bar) and (<FLAG>) - and continue on if the flag is missing?

Comment: `[A-Za-z ]*` will match only alphabetic characters and spaces. `[^<]*` will match anything that **isn't** a `<`. Etc.

Comment: OMG Thanks! I think I solved it. I've updated the code above. At least, it works in BBEdit 11. There's an odd RETURN here and there, like the closing title tag for Wom The Bat gets kicked to the next line, but I'm not going to complain. If anyone knows how to zap that, I'll still take tips. :-)

Comment: Editing a question with solved code/etc. is generally not the way things work here. You can answer your own question though. So post the updated code, the generated output, and why the original code was mistaken and then accept the answer. (And revert your edits to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

---

**This appears to get the job done (at least, in BBEdit 11)!**

```
^([A-Za-z. ]+[^<])(<[A-Z]{4}>)?(\r?\n?)([A-z].*)(\r?\n?)([A-z].*)(\r?\n?){1}
```

---

**And the correct output**

```
<item>
<category>Obituary</category>
<title>Wom The. Bat
</title>
<description>
<em>May 2, 2015</em><br />
Wom The Bat, 91, of city, formerly of Texas, died in the hospital. He was born in city, California. He is survived by two sons. Condolences: somewebsite.com.
</description>
<pubDate><DATE></pubDate>

</item>

<item>
<category>Obituary</category>
<title>Baz Foo Bar</title>
<description>
<em>April 30, 2015</em><br />
Baz Foo Bar, 88, of city, an Internal Revenue Service tax examiner, died at home. She was born in another city. She is survived by three daughters; 5 grandchildren; and 2 great-grandchildren. Services: 10:30 a.m. Private burial.
</description>
<pubDate><DATE></pubDate>
<FLAG>
</item>

<item>
<category>Obituary</category>
<title>John Doe</title>
<description>
<em>April 17, 2015</em><br />
John F. Doe, 51, of city, a structural engineer, died in the city. He was born in the Philippines. He is survived by his wife, son, daughter, and two parents. Visitation: 9:30 a.m. Monday. Eulogy: 10:30 a.m. Mass: 11:15 a.m. Burial: 1 p.m.
</description>
<pubDate><DATE></pubDate>
<FLAG>
</item>

<item>
<category>Obituary</category>
<title>Jane Smith
</title>
<description>
<em>May 1, 2015</em><br />
Jane "Mary" Smith, 64, of city, a storage specialist, died in the hospital. She was born in city, Rhode Island. She is survived by a son; two brothers; four sisters; and her caregiver. Graveside services: 11 a.m. Monday at cemetary. Urn burial to follow. Condolences: somewebsite.com.
</description>
<pubDate><DATE></pubDate>
</item>
```